# Fix for the Subnet Missing Required Delegation

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, subnet, vnet

I have a Azure Resource Group and it has a vnet. The vnet has a subnet which has two service endpoints configured namely **Microsoft.keyVault** and **Microsoft.Storage** and the subnet also has a subnet delegation to  **Microsoft.Web/serverFarms**.

Now I want to add another service endpoint **Microsoft.ServiceBus** to the same vnet using Azure Powershell. I executed the below code for that.

```
$virtualNetwork = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName 
Set-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $virtualNetwork.Subnets.Name -VirtualNetwork $virtualNetwork -AddressPrefix  $virtualNetwork.Subnets.AddressPrefix -ServiceEndpoint "Microsoft.ServiceBus"
$virtualNetwork | Set-AzVirtualNetwork
```

But the above code is throwing error at the last line of code saying that the **Subnet is missing Required Delegation**

```
Subnet requires any of the following delegation(s) [Microsoft.Web/serverFarms] to reference service association link 
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: Bad Request
ErrorCode: SubnetMissingRequiredDelegation
```

But in portal I see it has the required delegation. How to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though i have already added these service endpoint in my specific subnet and subnet also has a subnet delegation to `Microsoft.Web/serverFarms` able to add another service endpoint `Microsoft.ServiceBus`.

I would suggest you to use the following PowerShell script:

[image]

[image]

PowerShell Script:

```
$subscription = "b83c1edXXXXXXX-XXX"
$subnets = @('TestSubnet')
$vnetName = "Vnet1"
$vnetRgName = "X-rasXXXX-XX"
$newEndpoint = "Microsoft.ServiceBus"
    
Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription
foreach($snet in $subnets){
    Write-Host "Modifying Service Endpoints for subnet: $snet" -fore red -back white
    $virtualNetwork = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetName -ResourceGroupName $vnetRgName | Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $snet
    $addrPrefix = $virtualNetwork.AddressPrefix

    #Get existing service endpoints
    $ServiceEndPoint = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[String]'
    $virtualNetwork.ServiceEndpoints | ForEach-Object { $ServiceEndPoint.Add($_.service) }
    if ($ServiceEndPoint -notcontains $newEndPoint){
        $ServiceEndPoint.Add($newEndpoint)
    }

    $delegation=$virtualNetwork.Delegations

    #Add new service endpoint
    Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetName -ResourceGroupName $vnetRgName | Set-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $snet -AddressPrefix $addrPrefix -ServiceEndpoint $ServiceEndPoint -Delegation $delegation | Set-AzVirtualNetwork
}
```

[image]
[image]

Reference : [Azure Powershell - Applying multiple service endpoints to a subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54579309/azure-powershell-applying-multiple-service-endpoints-to-a-subnet)

Comment: Thanks Rahul, Any idea why it is throwing error saying subnet missing required delegation even though it has the delegation?

Comment: Not exactly sure but the cmdlet you are using that overwrite the existing service endpoint and will delete the existing subnet delegation as well. In process this might be cause for the error.

Comment: Understood, Thanks!

Comment: Hi Rahul, Can you please look into this question?     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71880180/associating-a-nat-to-a-subnet-is-giving-subnetmissingrequireddelegation-error