# Associating a NAT to a subnet is giving SubnetMissingRequiredDelegation error

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, nat, azure-virtual-network, subnet

I have created a **NAT gateway** and I have an existing **vnet** which has an **subnet**. My function app already has a vnet integration. I want to **integrate the nat gateway to the existing vnet**. All the function app, NAT, vnet and the subnet are in the same resource group.

My subnet has a subnet delegation to **Microsoft.Web/serverFarms**.

Now when I try to integrate the NAT gateway to the subnet using below code

```
$virtualNetwork = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
Set-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $virtualNetwork.Subnets.Name -AddressPrefix $virtualNetwork.Subnets.AddressPrefix -VirtualNetwork $virtualNetwork -InputObject $natGateway
$virtualNetwork | Set-AzVirtualNetwork
```

I am getting the below error saying

```
Set-AzVirtualNetwork : Subnet
/subscriptions/6acxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/ResouceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnetname/subnets/Subnet1 requires any of the
following delegation(s) [Microsoft.Web/serverFarms] to reference service association link /subscriptions/6acxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/ResouceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnetname/subnets/Subnet1/serviceAssociationLinks/AppServiceLink.
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: Bad Request
ErrorCode: SubnetMissingRequiredDelegation
```

But my vnet already has the required delegation with name **Microsoft.Web/serverfarms**. How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

**I tried with this below powershell cmdlet to set `NatGateway` in a `subnet`.But i am getting a ***warning*** only without error. I am using powershell version 5.x and 7.x as well to run this cmdlet.**

[image]

```
  $ResourceGroupName="v-XXXX-XXX"
    $natGateway=Get-AzNatGateway -ResourceGroupName "v-XXXX-XXX" -Name "TestNatGateway"
    $virtualNetwork = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
    Set-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $virtualNetwork.Subnets.Name -AddressPrefix $virtualNetwork.Subnets.AddressPrefix -VirtualNetwork $virtualNetwork -NatGateway $natGateway
    $virtualNetwork | Set-AzVirtualNetwork
```

> WARNING: Upcoming breaking changes in the cmdlet
> 'Set-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig' : Update Property Name Cmdlet
> invocation changes :
> Old Way : -ResourceId
> New Way : -NatGatewayId Update Property Name Cmdlet invocation changes :
> Old Way : -InputObject
> New Way : -NatGateway Note : Go to https://aka.ms/azps-changewarnings for steps to suppress this breaking
> change warning, and other information on breaking changes in Azure
> PowerShell.

Even though i have used `-NatGateway` instead of `-InputObject` i am getting the same warning and `Natgateway` is not able to set to the subnet.

Seems their is breaking changes or bug in `Set-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig`. So this may be the reason it is not working as expected.You can check many bug has reported regarding `Set-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig` using this [***Link***](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues?q=set-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig)

**So for workaorund please use portal only to set Nat Gatway to the subnet. using portal it is working fine.**